# How and why does $\int\frac{m^kx^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx$ become $(\frac{m}{m-s})^k\int\frac{(m-s)^k x^{k-1}e^{-(m-s)x}}{(k-1)!}dx$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does
$$\int\frac{m^kx^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx$$
become
$$\left( \frac{m}{m-s}\right)^k \int \frac{(m-s)^k x^{k-1}  e^{-(m-s)x}}{(k-1)!} dx $$

I understand how they collected the like terms with the exponent and that they took the $m^k$ outside the integral at the start, but have absolutely no idea where and why the $$ (m-s)^k$$ came from, both in the denominator outside the integral and in the numerator inside the integral.

Can explain what they did there??

Note, the integral is from $0$ to infinity which equals 1, not sure if that's important.

Comment: They just multiplied the whole expression by $(\frac{m-s}{m-s})^k=1$. As this is independent of $x$ they  took the denominator outside the integral.

Comment: Yes but why $$\left( \frac{m-s}{m-s} \right)^k$$ how would you know to do that?

Comment: If you take the parenthesis inside the integral, you can simplify the $(m-s)^k$ terms.

Comment: Still not understanding where it came from and why

Comment: *Why* they did it is impossible to know just by looking at the equations. Probably it allows for some useful interpretation of the equation. What I can tell you is *what* they did.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that for any integral with integrand $f(x)$ and where $a$ is a constant,
$$\int af(x)~ {dx}=a\int f(x)~dx$$
In your case, as
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{m^kx^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx&=\int m^k\times\frac{x^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx\\
&=\int m^k\times\frac{(m-s)^k}{(m-s)^k}\times\frac{x^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx\\
&=\int \frac{m^k}{(m-s)^k}\times(m-s)^k\times\frac{x^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx\\
&=\int \left(\frac{m}{m-s}\right)^k\times(m-s)^k\times\frac{x^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx\\
&=\left(\frac{m}{m-s}\right)^k\int (m-s)^k\times\frac{x^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx\\
&=\left(\frac{m}{m-s}\right)^k\int \frac{(m-s)^kx^{k-1}e^{-mx}e^{sx}}{(k-1)!} dx\end{align}$$

Does that help? Please tell me if you don't understand something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand why they did that, my question is more about "why" that particular fraction?

Comment: @Jimmy ok. It's pretty hard for us to know why they did that  unless you provide us with some more context. For example, what did they do with the integral afterwards? In what problem did you encounter this?

Comment: OK the original integral represents a gamma distribution and the purpose is to find the Moment generating function of said distribution